# iOS - How to set image to ImageView according to a specific value

Tags: ios, uiimageview, xcasset

I have several images, and I would like to set the image of my ImageView according to a specific value I get from web service.

For example if I got value "dog" I have to set image of a dog.

All the images are in my xcassets repertory.

Should I make a Switch for that ? Or is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: P you can create an array of image names getting from server and populate accordingly.

Comment: You can rename your all images in xcassets in a prefixed order . Suppose , `dog.png` for `dog` and so on . Then call the path as their names are .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the web service returns the same names used in your assets then you can just use the returned name directly as the name of the image to use like this:

```
let newImage: UIImage? = UIImage(named: imageName) // imageName is the name returned to you by the web service.
self.myUIImageView.image = newImage
```

Answer (score 0):

lets say you are getting "dog" value from the web service, and you have "dog" image saved in .xcassests folder, then you can simply use the same name to specify the image name. Ideally create the same image name coming from the server in .xcassets folder to correctly map the image.

assuming you have Model as Data struct and imageName property stores the image name

```
struct Data {
  let imageName: String
}

let imageName = data.imageName //"dog"
imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
```